# How to add dual variables to the Optimization Problem defined using optidef

Tags: math-mode, align, optidef

I have the following code,

```
\begin{mini*}
{}{\sum_{i}\sum_{j} c_{ij}x_{ij}}{}{} 
\addConstraint{\sum_{j \in \mathcal{P}} s_{xj}} {=1 \quad}{}{\quad \alpha}
\addConstraint{\sum_{p \in \mathcal{P}^{k}}y_{p}^{k}}{= 1\quad}{}{ \quad \beta}
\addConstraint{\sum_{p \in \mathcal{P}^{k}}y_{p}^{k}}{= 1\quad}{\forall i = s,t}{ \quad \gamma}
\end{mini*}
```

The above code is supposed to output an optimization problem and the `\alpha`, `\beta` and `\gamma` are the dual variables. I want them aligned to the right and maybe even in a different color as shown in the below code.

[image]

Could someone let me know if I can do this in optidef or should I use a basic align environment.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a good reason for not using an `align` environment, along with `\tag` instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\mathclap" macro
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} \quad 
   &\sum_{i}\sum_{j} c_{ij}x_{ij} \\
\text{subject to} \quad
   &\sum_{\mathclap{j\in\mathcal{P}}} s_{xj}=1,         \tag{$\alpha$}\\
   &\sum_{\mathclap{p\in\mathcal{P}^{k}}} y_{p}^{k}= 1, \tag{$\beta$} \\
   &\sum_{\mathclap{p\in\mathcal{P}^{k}}} y_{p}^{k}= 1\quad\forall i=s,t \tag{$\gamma$}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```